# How do I throw an exception for division by 0?

Tags: java, exception, constructor, try-catch, private-methods

How do I throw an exception such that it will output "Calculation failed, there is no change between x1 and x2" if my slope's denominator is 0...The following block is a method within a class file.

```
public double getSlope() {
    double rise = p2.getY() - p1.getY();
    double run  = p2.getX() - p1.getX();
    double slope = rise / run;
    return slope;
}
```

I'm outputting the results to my Testing file, or driver class containing a main method.

Comment: `if(denominator == 0) // tell the user that he cannot divide by zero`

Comment: but there is a slope at 90 degree

Comment: If you don't care what kind of exception is thrown, you don't have to do anything: an `ArithmeticException` will already be thrown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (run == 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Divide by zero error");
}
```

Comment: spelling in the string... ^ xD

Answer (score 1):

To throw the exception you need to do this:

```
public double getSlope() {
    double rise = p2.getY() - p1.getY();
    double run  = p2.getX() - p1.getX();
    if (run == 0) throw new Exception(
                   "Calculation failed, there is no change between x1 and x2");
    double slope = rise / run;
    return slope;
}
```

Notice the keyword `throw` in the method, this will be obviously un-caught from the `main` method and so will crash!

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
if(run == 0) {
    throw new java.lang.ArithmeticException("Calculation failed, there is no change between x1 and x2");
}
double slope = rise / run;
```

Also, you can use `java.lang.IllegalStateException` instead, if it makes more sense.

Or, `java.lang.RuntimeException` if you only the message is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

When you divide by zero, it throws automatically an exception called java.lang.ArithmeticException.

If you really want to throw your own exception, to put your message or something similar, you can as bellow:

```
if(run == 0) {
    throw new ArithmeticException("Your message here");
}
```

Please notice that this is a RuntimeException and you are not obligated to handle it. If you want to create something that forces the developer to handle, you can create your own Exception, but I think it's not the case.

Comment: That holds true only for integers. `1.0 / 0` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function as follows:

```
public double getSlope() throws DivideByZero{
    double rise = p2.getY() - p1.getY();
    double run  = p2.getX() - p1.getX();

    if (run == 0) {
        throw new MyException("Denominator is zero");
    }

    double slope = rise / run;
    return slope;
}
```

My answer also requires that you create a custom exception class called `MyException`. The details about doing this are left as an exercise for the reader. (Hint: Google is a great tool.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public double getSlope() throws Exception {
    double rise = p2.getY() - p1.getY();
    double run  = p2.getX() - p1.getX();
    if (run == 0) throw new Exception("Calculation failed.");
    double slope = rise / run;
    return slope;
}

public class TestLine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            l1.getSlope();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```